# Method get() pass value but set() return null

Tags: java, android, constructor, get, set

As follows, constructors are generally used to create and assign values to object instance variables
And the accessors and modifiers allow you to capture and configure things, in this case instance variables

I pass the set but when I call get it returns null

here I create a class and its constructor with their instance variables:

```
public class Esquema {
    private int goleiro;
    private Atleta goleiroobj;


    public Esquema()
    {


    }

    public Atleta getGoleiroobj() {
        return goleiroobj;
    }

    public void setGoleiroobj(Atleta goleiroobj) {
        this.goleiroobj = goleiroobj;
    }


    public int getGoleiro() {
        return goleiro;
    }

    public void setGoleiro(int goleiro) {
        this.goleiro = goleiro;
    }
}
```

I call my set() here :

```
private static  Esquema getEsquemaOrganize(Atleta atleta, Esquema esquema) {
        switch (atleta.getPosicaoId()){
                //GOLEIRO
            case 1 : esquema.setGoleiro(atleta.atleta_id);
                esquema.setGoleiroobj(MercadoManager.getAtleta(esquema.getGoleiro()));
                break;
```

I call my get here :

```
public class EsquemaTaticoViewHolder {


    private LinearLayout lay_goleiro;

    private TextView nome_goleiro;


    public EsquemaTaticoViewHolder() {

    }

    public EsquemaTaticoViewHolder(View view, Esquema esquema) {

        nome_goleiro = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome_goleiro);

        lay_goleiro = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lay_goleiro);

        if(esquema.getGoleiro() > 0){

            nome_goleiro.setText(esquema.getGoleiroobj().apelido);
            lay_goleiro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `atleta.atleta_id` in `esquema.setGoleiro(atleta.atleta_id);` is not returning `null`?

Comment: Yes, I debug and it set a value but does not get

Comment: And `esquema` in your second block of code is the same object as in the first one?

Comment: print the `hashcode()` after each call to `esquema` -are they the same?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.
My Fragment is the first screen to be started, so get gets started next to the Fragment.
I think I'm initializing the get before the set, but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: Well the easy way to check is using break points or logging.

Comment: You are not showing how you call `getEsquemaOrganize()` with an object instance. Nor are you showing how and where you call `EsquemaTaticoViewHolder()` with the same Esquema object. So there is litte to say.

Comment: I still can not solve my problem, I'm a beginner in java and I'm sure I'm making a small stupid mistake, can you help me please? :(